# Regex nth Sequence Before/After Dot

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have the following string, of which I want to get lastName, firstName, middleName, and id (the first four pieces of the string).

```
var str = 'SMITH.JOHN.DOE.1234567890, OU=USN, OU=PKI, OU=FOO, O=BAR, C=US';
```

I'm having a hard time writing a RegEx that will give me the nth sequence before each dot. I have something along the lines of this, but it's not working like I'd expect (I'm very far from a Regex expert):

```
 /(.*?(?=[\.\,])){0}(.*?(?=[\.\,]))/g
```

In the end I want `lastName = 'SMITH'`, `firstName = 'JOHN'`, `middleName = 'DOE'`, and `id = 1234567890`, all without leading or trailing periods/commas.

I did write one specifically for lastName, but I don't want to write specific ones for each variable. I'd rather be able to simply change an index skip number:

```
str.match(/^.*?(?=\.)/) => 'SMITH'
```

Using `/.*?(?=[\.\,])/g` splits on the values I want, but the system I'm setting up is going to pull each value using it's own Regex, not using loops. That's why I'm trying to pluck exact values.

I can implement this in either Java or JavaScript, but I'd probably prefer Java.

Comment: You need to split with `,`+space, then split the `chunk[0]` with `.`.

Comment: That's a very simple approach but won't suffice for how this is being written.

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify *won't suffice for how this is being written*.

Comment: My code needs to be `String lastName = str.match(lastNameRegex)[0];`. No loops, no extra logic, as I already stated in my question.

Comment: So, Java or JS? Please precise.

Comment: Whatever you're more comfortable with, I can convert them around if I need to. I am mainly just trying to figure out the proper way to get the nth sequence value, because what I'm reading `{n}` isn't working like I'm hoping.

Comment: See [`^(?:\.?([^.]*)){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/tI43Dw/1). Change the digit and see results.

Comment: That looks like it'll work, thanks! I was also being stupid and running `str.match` instead of `regexp.exec` which was causing me to thing some of my regexp were broken. Think I'm all set now, thanks again.

Comment: Maybe [`^(?:\.?([^,.]*)){4}`](https://regex101.com/r/tI43Dw/2) will work better, esp. for the ID.

Comment: Yep, I did alter it slightly to account for commas too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[^,.]+\.){3}([^,.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI43Dw/4)

Then, change 3 to the required index to grab the necessary value into Group 1.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^,.]+\.){3}` - 3 sequences (you can use here `{0}` to get the first value, `{1}` to get the second, etc.) of 1+ chars other than `,` and `.` (see `[^,.]+`) followed with a dot
- `([^,.]+)`  - Group 1 capturing 1+ chars other than `,` and `.`

Comment: Wiktor, I figured I'd try asking you quickly... I was thrown a wrinkle such that `middleName` may not exist so I could have `SMITH.JOHN.1234567890` or `SMITH.JOHN.DOE.1234567890` meaning `{2}` may give me the wrong value. I can still use what you provided for `lastName`, `firstName`, `middleName` with the possibility of tossing out `middleName` if it's an integer. Now in addition, I want to write a second expression that grabs everything before the first comma, backwards to the first found period (which would be the last period of that sequence). Would you be able to help with that?

Comment: Not now, I must go to bring my daughter from the kindergarten. Optional groups can be used for that. Or perhaps, 2 regexps.

Comment: I'm using `[^\.\,]*(?=,)` to capture id.

Comment: 1) Get all before the first comma: [`^[^,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/JL2dxF/1). 2) Get each part into a specific group: [`^([^.,]+)\.([^.,]+)(?:\.([^.,]+))?\.([^.,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/JL2dxF/3) (here, the third group is made optional with the help of a non-capturing group `(?:...)?`).

Comment: I didn't have a high enough rating until today, but I did just upvote. Thanks.